# Spring, a lot of SQL requests when i use `saveAll`

Tags: java, sql, spring

I have the following entity `Customer`:

```
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@Entity
@ToString(exclude = {"roles"})
@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
public class Customer {

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
  private long id;

  // attributes

  @OneToMany
  @JsonIgnore
  @JsonProperty(access = JsonProperty.Access.WRITE_ONLY)
  private List<Role> roles;

}
```

When i create a `customer` i do the following:

```
Customer createCustomer(Customer customer) {
    roleRepository.saveAll(customer.getRoles());
    return customerRepository.save(customer);
}
```

This results in 3n+2 sql requests if n is the number of roles. Heres an example when i try to create a customer with 3 roles:

```
2019-12-23 17:16:07.411 DEBUG 17156 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] org.hibernate.SQL                        : select nextval ('hibernate_sequence')
2019-12-23 17:16:07.412 DEBUG 17156 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] org.hibernate.SQL                        : select nextval ('hibernate_sequence')
2019-12-23 17:16:07.413 DEBUG 17156 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] org.hibernate.SQL                        : select nextval ('hibernate_sequence')
2019-12-23 17:16:07.414 DEBUG 17156 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] org.hibernate.SQL                        : insert into role (hourly_wage, name, id) values (?, ?, ?)
2019-12-23 17:16:07.415 DEBUG 17156 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] org.hibernate.SQL                        : insert into role (hourly_wage, name, id) values (?, ?, ?)
2019-12-23 17:16:07.416 DEBUG 17156 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] org.hibernate.SQL                        : insert into role (hourly_wage, name, id) values (?, ?, ?)
2019-12-23 17:16:07.427 DEBUG 17156 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] org.hibernate.SQL                        : select nextval ('hibernate_sequence')
2019-12-23 17:16:07.429 DEBUG 17156 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] org.hibernate.SQL                        : insert into customer (address, archived_date, is_archived, name, smallest_time_unit, smallest_time_unit_enabled, supplier_number, id) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
2019-12-23 17:16:07.431 DEBUG 17156 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] org.hibernate.SQL                        : insert into customer_roles (customer_id, roles_id) values (?, ?)
2019-12-23 17:16:07.432 DEBUG 17156 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] org.hibernate.SQL                        : insert into customer_roles (customer_id, roles_id) values (?, ?)
2019-12-23 17:16:07.434 DEBUG 17156 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] org.hibernate.SQL                        : insert into customer_roles (customer_id, roles_id) values (?, ?)
```

Is there any way to reduce the number of SQL requests? Isnt it possible to create all `roles` in one request and add all `roles` to a `customer` in one request?

Comment: It seems it is using the join table to map the relationship.Is this desired for your business case?

Comment: How could you map it otherwise in a @OneToMany relation?

Comment: You can have a foreign key in the child table and use this foreign key for driving the relationship.Generally ,if the relationship is not bi-directional then hibernate will create a join table to map the relationship.Try making the relationship bidirectional and you wont need the join table. You can refer this post https://vladmihalcea.com/the-best-way-to-map-a-onetomany-association-with-jpa-and-hibernate/

Comment: I could try that, that would get rid of the inserts into the join table. But i would still have 2n+2 requests right. In the example i posted above, i would only get rid of the last 3 requests. My main problem with a lot of sql queries was the fact that the remote database im using is 100km away, so i have a roundtriptime of several ms which adds up if i have a lot of requests. But i think i can fix this problem by using batches and sending all the insert requests in one batch.

Comment: These statements select nextval ('hibernate_sequence') are used for selecting and assigning the primary key to the table.

Comment: You can check hi-lo strategy.I have tested it seems there are reduced calls to get the sequences. https://vladmihalcea.com/the-hilo-algorithm/